# Number of roots of differentiable function

Tags: calculus

I have two related problems that are causing me big trouble:

Let $\;a_1,...,a_n\in\Bbb R\;,\;\;a_i\neq 0\;\;\forall\;i\;$ , and let $\;b_1,...,b_n\in\Bbb R\;,\;\;b_i\neq b_j\;\;\forall\,i\neq j\;$ .

(1) Prove that the equation

$$a_1x^{b_1}+\ldots+a_nx^{b_n}=0$$

has at most $\;n-1\;$ different zeros in $\;(0,\infty)\;$ (*Hint:* Use induction)

(2) Prove that the equation

$$a_1e^{b_1x}+\ldots+a_ne^{b_nx}=0$$

has at most $\;n-1\;$ different zeros in $\;\Bbb R\;$ .

Now, the following is what I've done so far: for a differentiable function $\;f\;$ ,  I can prove that if $\;f'(x)=0\;$ has $\;n-1\;$ different zeros, then $\;f(x)\;$ has at most $\;n\;$ different zeros, using the mean value theorem, say.

But I can't see how to use induction in this case: if I differentiate in the first problem, I get $$0=f'(x)=a_1b_1x^{b_1-1}+\ldots +a_nb_nx^{b_n-1}=\frac1x\sum_{i=1}^na_ib_ix^{b_i}$$

...and now?! How does induction kick in here? I though perhap something like: if we suppose WLOG $\;b_1<b_2<...<b_n\;$ , then perhaps inducting on $\;\lfloor b_n\rfloor\;$, but it gets messy and blurry if $\;b_n<0\;$...

Any help, hints are very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:  $a_1 x^{b_1} + \ldots + a_n x^{b_n}$ has the same number of roots in $(0,\infty)$ as $a_1 + \ldots + a_n x^{b_n - b_1}$.

Comment: Well, yes: that's another thing I tried, thank you very much, sir: $$\sum_{i=1}^na_ix^{b_i}=x^{b_1}\left(\sum_{i=1}^na_ix^{b_i-b_1}\right)$$, since $\;x^{b_1}\neq 0\;$ , but I'm still lost where induction gets in...on the number of powered $\;x\;$ ?

Comment: Oh, perhaps I get it! I can differentiate $\;a_1+a_2x^{b_2-b_1}+\ldots +a_nx^{b_n-b_1}\;$ and I remain with *less* than $\;n\;$ summands...!